# how to store multiple PRODUCTS's 'primary key' field in one ORDER's 'Order_Product' field?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

in a nutshell, i want to select multiple PRODUCT per one ORDER entry. should i use some string manipulation method to compose all selected product in one string and save it into single field ? it sounds obvious but i don't think its way to go because its like majority of database design confronts the order and its multiple products and there should be a better way to deal with it. please suggest a better practice or something magical like one can store multiple primary key in one foreign key field but seems like thats not the best practice somehow. so what should i do ?

```
Order_Product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
# im thinking of making below field into a string holding container
# and join many primary key and just outright save it separating by commas
Order_SelectedProduct = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

Order_Amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Order_Qty = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Order_Date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Order_Deadline = models.CharField(max_length=10)
Order_Reference = models.CharField(max_length=128)

def __str__(self):
    return self.Order_Id
```

obviously that Order_SelectedProduct field is not ideal way because one primary takes 14 spaces so say one order can only be limited to store only 71 products per order, thats more than enough but thats not scalable. i hope it yields something fruitfull

Comment: Have you tried using ManyToManyField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 2):

What you need is many-to-many relationship.

For this you can define your models as:

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

class Order(models.Model):
    Order_Product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    ...
```

Then, to add multiple products in the order object, you can do something like:

```
order = Order() --> create a order object
order.Order_Product.add(product1)
order.Order_Product.add(product2)
# product1 and product2 are the product objects that were selected
# and so on
order.save()
```

For more clarification, you can refer to [django many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: well, that many-to-many Field seems fair enough but this saving product.save() individually seems less efficient. its like i have a jquery functionality that loads products from select drop down to a table -> as product added in table -> by onKeyUp one enters Quantity -> and product gets enlisted in table, so all product are dynamically added through ajax so i cant do individual product_i.save(). but thanks for the efforts

Comment: Well you don't have to save the products every time to store in the order object. The above was just an example to clarify the use of many-to-many relationship. If you select multiple products to add to your order object, all you need to do is `order.Order_Product.add(product1, product2, product3, ...)` where the product objects are already saved.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Maybe you are confused on saving the product objects while adding the order.

Comment: thats more like it, ill give it a try